# Starting properties of objects in Winforms form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, properties, form-designer

In my software course, each time we submit an assignment, we have to include a document with the starting properties of each object in a form.

E.g.

```
TextBox1
Location: 241, 115
Name: TextBox1
Size: 100, 20
TabIndex: 0
```

It's a real pain to scroll through the properties viewer and copy and paste each customised value for 30+ objects on a form... I was wondering if there'd be an easy piece of code or way about getting an (at least partially) automated printout/view of all the properties of the objects.

Was thinking some sort of private sub I could past into the bottom of the program and run on load, that gets all objects, and outputs the non-default properties to a report or something? Basically any ideas on how I could do this?

Any help'd be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not look in the `InitializeComponent` Method, you should be able to cut and paste what you need from there.

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
    Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Label1
    '
    Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 46)
    Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
    Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(51, 17)
    Me.Label1.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Label1.Text = "Label1"
    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(8.0!, 16.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(282, 255)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "Form1"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub
```